# Hard knocking noise with temporary loss of power in a 2002 Jeep Cherokee

Tags: automatic-transmission, jeep, cherokee

I have been hearing a hard knocking noise for last couple of months off and on. But now since Monday my truck has been loosing power for like 30 seconds n then gains it back. The rpm goes up and then down and then it goes. Tonight it shut completely off and steering wheel locked. Wouldn't start but all lights and everything worked. After like two minutes it started. I just put a transmission in like year ago and radiator couple months ago. Can you please tell me what it could be.

Comment: Are you sure the knocking is coming from the transmission? In what conditions does this happen? Does it only happen while driving, under load, turning, at a stop, etc., etc.?